(C++) terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc
I wrote the code trying to search for a word in a string, for I was practicing pointers in C++.
First time when I tried this code is fine, but I wanted it to become decoupling and to practice passing pointer into function.
I then wrote some global function trying to perform the same things, but the console kept saying things like the title.
I put two versions below, first is the version that cannot be perform.
Please give me some advice or corrections about this problem or programming style.
I post a question for the first time, if the highlighting doesn't work please pardon me.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int serching(char*a , const char* b, const int n); // repeating serching desginated word in the ariticle.

int target(char*& a, int& b); // Let users enter a word.

int main()
{
    int timesA = 1; //recording the numbers of total words in article.
    int timesD = 0; //recording the numbers of designated words.
    const int maxlength = 10000;
    char a[maxlength];
    
    cout << "Please enter the paragraph less than " << maxlength <<  " characters. " << endl;
    
    cin.getline(a, maxlength);
    size_t l = strlen(a);
    
    cout << "Total numbers of characters: " << l << endl;
    
    char* aptr = new char [l]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        aptr[i] = a[i];
    }
    
    int n;
    char* desg;
    int num = target(desg, n);
    serching(aptr, desg, num);
        
    delete[] desg;
    desg = 0;
        
    cout << "There are " << timesD << " designated words found in this paeagraph. " << endl;
    
        
    delete[] aptr;
    aptr = 0;
    
    return 0;
} 

int serching(char*a , const char* b, const int n) 
{
    int num = 0;
    char* i  = strstr(a, b);
    while(i != 0)
    {
        num++;
        i = strstr((i + n), b);
    }
    delete[] i;
    i = 0;
    return num;
}

int target(char*& a, int& b)
{
    a = new char[b];
    cout << "Please enter a word: " << endl;
    cin.getline(a, 20);
    b = strlen(a);
    delete[] a;
    a = 0;
    return b;
}

Here is the original version which can be execute without problem:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int timesA = 1; //recording the numbers of total words in article.
    int timesD = 0; //recording the numbers of designated words.

    const int maxlength = 10000;    
    char a[maxlength];
    
    cout << "Please enter the paragraph less than " << maxlength <<  " characters. " << endl;
    
    cin.getline(a, maxlength);
    size_t l = strlen(a);
    
    cout << "Total numbers of characters: " << l << endl;
    
    char* aptr = new char [l]; //pass into a dynamic array, for I'm practcing this.
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        aptr[i] = a[i];
    }

    int n;
    char* desg = new char[n]; 
    cout << "Please enter a word: " << endl;
    cin.getline(desg, 20); 
    n = strlen(desg);
        
        
    char* i  = strstr(aptr, desg); // repeating serching the word in the string.
    while(i != 0)
    {
        timesD++;
        i = strstr((i + n), desg);
    }
    delete[] i;
    i = 0;
    delete[] desg;
    desg = 0;
        
    cout << "There are " << timesD << " designated words found in this paeagraph. " << endl;
    
    delete[] aptr;
    aptr = 0;

    return 0;
} 

I thought the problem might be leaking memory or some value is too big, I have seen some posts that have same console error context as me, but still cannot figure it out.

int n; followed by new char [n] is a bad combination. The variable n is not initialized, and will have an indeterminate value. And in C++ using an indeterminate value in any way leads to undefined behavior.

What's more, you allocate a lot of strings, but you forget that all plain C-style strings are really called null-terminated strings. The strlen function does not count the null-terminator needed to make sure that a string is really a string.

Lastly, I really hope this is just for exercise using pointers and dynamic allocation. Because otherwise you should be using std::string for all strings, and using standard C++ algorithms for finding things, etc.

You should absolutely not delete a pointer you got from strstr (although, since it must be the null pointer, nothing bad will happen). And target deletes the array  it allocated and assigns the null pointer to a.

Your old code has two new[]s and three delete[]s. This is wrong, and only works because one of the delete[] arguments is a null pointer. The new code has two new[]s and four delete[]s, which is even more wrong.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

@Someprogrammerdude Thanks your commemts. I want to ask about the dynamic allocation, if I write int n  = 0;  and put  cin >> ahead of new , this will be okay? And thank you for your adivce on using C++strring, but this is as you said for exercising pointer and somthing. The online course I took also said that C++string is more useful and general, that teacher taught this just for us to understand more about pointer...... though I still so confused.
